# running a shell script on my local computer that runs a script on aws ec2 instance - How can I follow the ongion output?

Tags: python, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run a shell script on my local computer, which in the end connects to my aws ec2 instance and runs another shell script on this:

```
   ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@$host "bash run_file.sh ${userInput}"
```

The other shell script 'run_file.sh' looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
source activate pytorch_p36
cd local_directory/libcpab-master/
echo "running ${1}..."
python ${1}
```

After the script has run I get all the outputs in my terminal but I would like to follow the outputs ongoing. How can this be done? If it is possible.

Comment: do them as separate steps ... first `ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@$host` then after you are ssh'd into the system run your bash command...

Comment: I have tried to write [bash run_file.sh] in the end of the first script, but nothing happens when I run it. I just connects to my instance and stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your realtime output and errors into a file, open a second window and use `tail -f`  option to check the output in realtime. Your ssh command will look like this:

```
ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@$host "bash run_file.sh ${userInput} 1>/path/to/logfile 2>>/path/to/logfile "
```

This file will be generated on the server you are connecting via `ssh`.

Comment: When I'm doing this I only see the outputs when the script are done running.

Comment: You can go more granular and put that logging commands in front of any command inside the script as well,  whenever the execution of that command is complete, the output will be logged into the file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Fixed it by putting flush=True in print statement.